# Is storing initializer_lists undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, c++17, undefined-behavior, initializer-list, variant

This question is a follow up to [How come std::initializer_list is allowed to not specify size AND be stack allocated at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72377360/how-come-stdinitializer-list-is-allowed-to-not-specify-size-and-be-stack-alloc)

The short answer was that calling a function with brace-enclosed list `foo({2, 3, 4, 5, 6});` conceptually creates a temporary array in the stackspace before the call and then passes the initializer list which (like string_view) just references this local temporary array (probably in registers):

```
int __tmp_arr[5] {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
foo(std::initializer_list{arr, arr + 5});
```

Now consider the following case where I have nested initializer_lists of an object "ref". This ref object stores primitives types or an initializer_list recursively in a variant. My question now is: Is this undefined behaviour? It appears to work with my code, but does it hold up to the standard? My reason for doubting is that when the inner constructor calls for the nested brace-enclosed lists return, the temporary array which the initializer list is refering to could be invalidated because the stack pointer is reset (thus saving the initializer_list in the variant preserves an invalid object). Writing to subsequent memory would then overwrite values refered to by the initializer list. Am I wrong in believing that?

[CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIAAcpAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcYl2mA4ZQgRMxARZPn4BldUCtfUERRHRsQm2dQ1NOa1D3aG9pf3xAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMocjeWADUJutuAG71eIYEB9gmGgCCG1s7mPuHCgTEocAA%2Bkd4mADul2udzMmwY2y8ewObmQr3wqEBtyBXjSRl2J1ozwAIrtYSAQCd3ucobiQCwBKk6gRMKRdqECDSoqhPDSSa93kZvr8/iyCOg8aF0mI8AAvWKfWh4V7Et5eBy7YiYKiA9ZXdZWRG3NmygjyxVAkwAdnVN12pt1VAgjM8swOxrN5ogdJtaqB9oVFrQDFeu2QCHqACpnXaze6ICSBY4haLiOLJRdDu7LkH9bd7ei0WIvJhPrb9QbMbmNTctXLPXVJsQ88HTWWmBWw7z%2BQxBRLo7GpQm9Srac2CLN9kbXfazUl2QQLeYzABaGezufzhcmACsbgYk%2BTqeHptHdPbBEdvY3JrNhoLRbTqDw6F2O8Ee4bfJAEbOrbFEo7bkT3fffaHpsN1bDvwxC7BAnreomZgAGzyrsIC7D%2B/YAX%2BW5mngVCgSSCCeOgCifGIVLEMwjhHJg0qPmSDAUkwVKXBAxAAHTolmnyzEhg6bqhqG3uOECTnSy6ruuhbHlx/75rsmC0EotIYQ%2BeLYbQuH4bQhHEXgpFQgJKr0UxmbZmxA6AWJI5jhOZhmAJK5rhZR4meJ2JSTJ6GYY2ICKcpBGxOpmmHFatB0YxzEGexxn2Tx5lmP5gk2WYdn2aeknSU8Lnye5OF4V5RE0RpZEvG5bIfJy/yBXp3ghUZKH2TeZl8RZhUcj8JXWcJLqcWJiVOSlclYRlKlqTlvluOGvYviKb5xlCX6qtgunBaxoVVeFtX8aNUYTa8IAxa1YUmTx94ksAmDxsNbnPutMY/lNXYzXN%2BkLSJ1WnktDkoc9iL5iJQLunioZ0j2hD9vB80ARGiUATVdKReYS7Xq8JCYOg20WTSEZBgOZ43D9IChv5AN9nBGblTmRpgxJEMRXVZgwwoOJEAqSMtSj%2BPPAAYvsFkymRFmE5OVBiEoO0Y99iq/YqYECN6voBvjQNEyxAGsm8RVNQCpO9s95NGpDgjQ2YS60/DDPIwEsu2sLtzY6GI0tuNl2TZ2SrdmjhMg%2BrhDg9rlOrbbbY/nTCOM0JzNo%2Bb713Lc/0sHWDAQDaH2AbWFY4qgbCfEnYQgQc2IQ1wNJczSS40hDyEWYQmAsMCpvU/mxeDmXVIsFYzNc5rBafW1dz5hw8y0JwS68H4HBaKQqCcG41jWCnSwrBz6w8KQBCaD38wANYgEuGj6JwkiD8vo%2BcLwCggFvS/Dz3pBwLAMCICgqdJHQsTkJQaAsA/9BxMACjMEkCjYfSNBVKxGPpafeURQj1AAJ6cAXq/NgggADyDBaDQPPqQLA0cjDiDQfgBU1RSLHzQZgVQVQvBUn3nSKS%2B8JRRGIFAjwWB97KxYDAi%2BVADBfwAGpcgQUkRgrCZCCBEGIdgUhBHyCUGofeug84GCMCgSelh9B4CiMfSA8xUBJEcJLTgM5YTZ1MJYawXADRHyklUbRfgICuBGH4POwRJglDKHoFIaRLG2JcfkSxPQnH9Dzm0SxnRhieGaHoAJNRxg%2BL6HEfx4wPGxK6FE6YMT5gKEWMsURi8FSrB4L3fue80Fjw4KoeIUEpxQUkLsYAyBkCgRlAwVe/YIATyMUo3YuBCAkDnnnXYHg36PyziCLgsxeBny0GxUg69N7bw4LvUgLDJDrAYusJcBp1hQRWZIMwayACckgi5DxHkUo%2BJ9F7L3mFfW%2BiwCBJDIc/CW/SP7hFYKsEpZSKk%2BjkcAOpxAvANJGYEfA9Mrx6H4EI0Q4gxFgokSodQaCZGkD%2BHQpIrC8kcAHqQQ5vAikILIbcnUqAMJvPKZU6ptSID1MaaBPp79YjdIBWMlepAECYCYFgOIccZlzJYUuKCDEKnQXWfsg00ENBLgOfvY5thTmMomVMrefcODrAKUcw%2BZzz4TMVWYFV2K1WyvmKRYgaRnCSCAA%3D%3D%3D)

```
#include <variant>
#include <string_view>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdio>

using val = std::variant<std::monostate, int, bool, std::string_view, std::initializer_list<struct ref>>;

struct ref
{
    ref(bool);
    ref(int);
    ref(const char*);
    ref(std::initializer_list<ref>);

    val value_;
};

struct container
{
    container(std::initializer_list<ref> init) {
        printf("---------------------\n");
        print_list(init);
    }

    void print_list(std::initializer_list<ref> list)
    {
        for (const ref& r : list) {
            if (std::holds_alternative<std::monostate>(r.value_)) {
                printf("int\n");
            } else if (std::holds_alternative<int>(r.value_)) {
                printf("int\n");
            } else if (std::holds_alternative<bool>(r.value_)) {
                printf("bool\n");
            } else if (std::holds_alternative<std::string_view>(r.value_)) {
                printf("string_view\n");
            } else if (std::holds_alternative<std::initializer_list<ref>>(r.value_)) {
                printf("initializer_list:\n");
                print_list(std::get<std::initializer_list<ref>>(r.value_));
            }
        }
    }
};

ref::ref(int init) : value_{init} { printf("%d stored\n", init); }
ref::ref(bool init) : value_{init} { printf("%s stored\n", init ? "true" : "false"); }
ref::ref(const char* init) : value_{std::string_view{init}} { printf("%s stored\n", init); }
ref::ref(std::initializer_list<ref> init) : value_{init} { printf("initializer_list stored\n", init); }

int main()
{
    container some_container = { 1, true, 5, { {"itemA", 2}, {"itemB", true}}};
}
```

Output:

```
1 stored
true stored
5 stored
itemA stored
2 stored
initializer_list stored
itemB stored
true stored
initializer_list stored
initializer_list stored
---------------------
int
bool
int
initializer_list:
initializer_list:
string_view
int
initializer_list:
string_view
bool
```

Comment: You should remove unrelated code. what you ask has no relation to `std::variant`.

Comment: Let's put it this way: I would only ever use a `std::initializer_list` while it is in scope, just like any other local variable.

Comment: *Storing* the list may not be UB but accessing its members after the 'source' has gone out of scope almost certainly is.

Comment: @AdrianMole Well that is my question. _Is_ the source out of scope when the container constructor is executed?

Comment: temporary lifetime end at full expression.

Comment: @appleapple No it doesn't answer it. The full expression of the outermost call to the constructor of container ends after the constructor has been called, yes. So the outermost initializer list  will be fine and can be used by the containers constructor. But when do the expressions end for the calls that go out to the constructors of the inner elements of the brace-enclosed initializer lists? Can I still use them in my container constructor or will they be out of scope already?

Comment: @glades I don't get what you're saying. there is no inner call afaict?

Comment: @glades you should provide [mcve], not something that involve `std::variant` and a lot of overload and conversions so we (and yourself) can better understand your think.

Comment: @glades fwiw, in your own example, it's pretty clear that all object are constructed before you ever enter the `container`'s constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, copying a `std::initializer_list` does not copy the underlying objects. ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list))

---

and

```cpp
container some_container = { 1, true, 5, { {"itemA", 2}, {"itemB", true}}};
```

actually compiles to something like

```cpp
container some_container = { // initializer_list<ref>
   ref{1}, 
   ref{true}, 
   rer{5},
   ref{ // initializer_list<ref>
      ref{ // initializer_list<ref>
         ref{"itemA"}, 
         ref{2}
      }, 
      ref{ // initializer_list<ref>
         ref{"itemB"},
         ref{true}
      }
   }
};
```

and all those object's lifetime* end at end of full expression (the `;` here)

<sub>*including all `initializer_list<ref>`, their underlying array, and all the belonging `ref` objects, but not the one in the constructor (copy elision may apply though)</sub>

---

so

1. yes it's fine to use those object in the constructor.
2. those object are gone after the `;` so you should not use the stored object (in `initializer_list`) anymore

---

[godbolt example with noisy destructor and action after the construction](https://godbolt.org/z/d7KMjorsW)

Comment: Thank you but I still got a question: Let's enumerate the constructors taking initializer_lists by level: 1,2 and 3 whereas 3 is the constructor which takes an initializer list containing "itemA" and 2. Now before constructor 3  is called, a temporary array of "itemA" and 2 is preallocated on the stack and its initializer_list is then passed to constructor 3 which stores it in its member. But this happens at scope of constructor 2 which terminates after the last "initializer_list stored" is printed. Isn't now the temporary array mentioned before officialy out of scope and therefore invalid?

Comment: @glades no, the array also goes out of scope after the full expression `;` (as can be seen in the linked example. all destructor are only called after the constructor of `container` runs).

Comment: i.e. all `std::initializer_list` and their underlying arrays and all `ref` are only destoryed after the full expression ends.

Comment: @glades if you're refer to the `std::initializer_list` pass by value in the constructor. it does goes out of scope. but  the original `std::initializer_list` that created before passed to the constructor  and the underlying object is not, and the copy (which you stored) can still access it no problem.

Comment: @glades btw, re *a temporary array of "itemA" and 2 is preallocated on the stack*, no, you're passing a `std::initializer_list<ref>` so the array is actually `{ref{"itemA"},ref{1}}`

Comment: Ahh so that means that the original initializer_list is never placed in scoped context (as I suspected is always the case for automatic variables) and waits for the full expression to return? Also can you put that bit in your answer it's really helpful!